# Why isn't my django templating working?

Tags: python, django, html, templates, django-templates

I've got some django templating I'm doing where it won't render a block.
The block looks like:

```
{% block compose %}
    {% load static %}
    <some html></some html>
{% endblock %}
```

And I have the block being called in my base.html like so:

```
<div id="fixedComp">
     {% block compose %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

If anyone can tell me why it isn't rendering it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you extend your base as in `{% extends "base.html" %}`?

Comment: I tried both with and without `{% extends "base.html" %}` and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: You should tell us more about your `views.py`, and your directory structure.

Comment: the compose block has nothing in views.py, it's static html being loaded into the base.html and the path is /mailer/mailer/base.html and /mailer/dbmanager/templates/compose.html

Comment: Does removing `{% load static %}` help?

Comment: You are not 'loading' a block inside your `base.html`, it is the other way around. You re-use the base.html from your `compose.html`. That's why we want to see your views.py where you render `compose.html`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends

Comment: This is what I have in views.py 

    `def compose:
        return render(request, 'compose.html')`

and what do you mean by "loading"

Comment: Removing `{% load static %}` does not make a difference.

Comment: Try moving your base.html to templates directory and then extend it in compose.html